# Jqgrid advance search, all search operators not displaying in search operator dropdown

Tags: model-view-controller, search, jqgrid

Can anybody have an idea that how to populate all search operators like
equal to, not equal to, less than, not less then, greater than, not greater than, etc etc in jqgrid advance search operator dropdown????

Comment: It's the default behavior of jqGrid., but some search operators has no   sense with some data types. For example in case of usage `stype:'select'` one use typically `searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] }` **to reduce** the list of operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }
```

This line is a property of a column and goes in the definition of a column in the colModel property of the grid:

```
 $("#MyTable").jqGrid({
 colModel: [
 { name: "outputid", index: "outputid", width: 30, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn']} },
 { other columns ...}
 ],
 otherProperty: ...
```

You can also set

```
search: false
```

instead and searches will not be allowed on that column.